# Giving values to checboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable named total=0; How can I increment it's value with the value of the button that has been pressed?

```
<script>
    var pressed = $(this).attr('id');
    total = total + document.getElementById(pressed).value;

</script>
```

How can I do it?

SOLVED by using Jeff's idea which he wrote in the comment section:

```
total += parseInt( document.getElementById(pressed).value);
```

Thank you!

Comment: _"Is this the right way to do it?"_ Is `total` set to expected value?

Comment: When I press a button, the variable called total will be increased with the value of the pressed button. So if myBtn1.value=3 and I press myBtn1, the total will be 0+3=3.

Comment: All interactive elements (button, inputs etc) values are stored as strings. You need to convert the value to an integer before adding i.e. total += parseInt( document.getElementById(pressed).value, 10);

Comment: Try `total = total + (+document.getElementById(pressed).value)`

Comment: What is that 10 in the end?

Comment: To ensure that the value is a decimal number and not an octal number. Modern browsers now default to radix 10 (decimal)